# Does new relic supports socks5 proxy type?

Tags: java, proxy, performance-testing, newrelic

I'm trying to collect my new relic data through SSH Dynamic Proxy (SSH Port Forwarding) but it supports only socks5 proxy type.

Does new relic supports socks5 proxy type? It is transparent? How to define this in the settings?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the New Relic Java Agent (based on your SO tags), it only supports basic (clear text) authentication.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-configuration

Comment: it isn't related with authentication. See this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#Comparison_to_HTTP_proxying